# SQL - group by based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a table with the following columns. It is used to keep track of software application that users run on their computers with start and end dates.

```
UserID  StartDate  EndDate    AppName        AppCategory
001     1/1/2013   1/5/2013   MS Word        Office
001     1/1/2013   1/4/2013   MS Excel       Office
001     1/1/2013   1/4/2013   Visual Studio  Development
002     .......    ........   .............  .........
```

I would like to find out which users are running more than one application (at the same time) in the same Application Category all for more than 2 days.

In the sample data above, User 001 was running Word and Excel in the 'Office' category and both apps ran more than 2 days at the same time.

How would you write the SQL query for that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select Distinct UserId, AppName From table t
Where Datediff(day, startDate, EndDate) > 2
   And Exists
      (Select * From table
       Where userId = t.userId 
          And AppCategory = t.AppCategory
          And Datediff(day, startDate, EndDate) > 2
       Having Count(distinct Appname) > 1)
```

Comment: Charles, thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention a requirement in the original question so I modified it. Would it be possible for you to update your query accordinly?...more than one app running 'at the same time' more than 2 days...